# Displaying image from db in Razor/MVC5 (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, controller

I'am new in ASP.net... I tried to Display an Image from an MySql DataBase but nothing shows ...
In my Product Class I have a List of a Pictures :

```
public partial class product
{
    public product()
    {
        this.orderitems = new List<orderitem>();
        this.pictures = new List<picture>();
        this.productitemsuppliers = new List<productitemsupplier>();
        this.recommendations = new List<recommendation>();
        this.reviews = new List<review>();
        this.productitems = new List<productitem>();
    }
```

I habve this Method in  my ProductController:

```
     static IDatabaseFactory dbFact = new DatabaseFactory();
        IUnitOfWork utOfW = new UnitOfWork(dbFact);

        public FileContentResult imageGenerate(int id)
        {
            byte[] image = utOfW.ProductRepository.GetById(id).pictures.ElementAt(0).picture1;
              // Another way to get the Byte Array from the Database...
            //  byte[] image = utOfW.PictureRepository.GetMany(p=>p.product.idProduct==id).ElementAt(0).picture1;
   if (image != null)  {
           return new FileContentResult(image, "image/jpg");
        }
             return null;
        }
```

and in my View :

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
....
  <td>
 <img id="image" src='@Url.Action("imageGenerate", "ProductController", new { id = item.idProduct})'/>
  </td>

}
```

It seems to be ok but the reseult isn't...

[image]

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if you can see the file using just simple web request, e.g. `http://youraddress/Product/imageGenerate/5`. If you can't, then it is an issue with generating of an image.

If you can see the image, then it is likely that you are using `ProductController' in your view. You only need to specify name of the controller without extension`Controller`. So your image code should look like the following:

```
<img id="image" src='@Url.Action("imageGenerate", "Product", new { id = item.idProduct})'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@dotnetom 
First thank you for your quick answer ... 
I changed the call to :

```
<img id="image" src='@Url.Action("imageGenerate", "Product", new { id = item.idProduct})'/>
```

but now I have an another Problem :

[image]

But I am quite sure that this Method works I have tested it in the Index Method of the ProductController

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var products = db.products.Include(p => p.category).Include(p => p.promotion).Include(p => p.user);
            ViewBag.Count = utOfW.ProductRepository.GetById(1).pictures.Count(); // the result is 3 and it is true 

            return View(products.ToList());
        }
```